# CREATE after OPTIONAL MATCH where no match was found

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to write a query that will create some relationships if another relationship already exists.

```
START a=node(1), b=node(2), c=node(3)
OPTIONAL MATCH a-[r1:RELATIONSHIP]-(optional1)
OPTIONAL MATCH b-[r2:RELATIONSHIP]-(optional2)
CREATE c-[:NEW_RELATIONSHIP]->(optional1)
CREATE c-[:NEW_RELATIONSHIP]->(optional2)
DELETE r1, r2
RETURN a, b, c
```

The query returns an error:

"Expected `optional1` to a node, but it is a null"

Is there a way to create the new relationship if the existing relationship exists? Otherwise just ignore the create?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For now, you can work around this using `FOREACH` and `CASE`. For example:

```
START a=node(1), b=node(2), c=node(3)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[r1:RELATIONSHIP]-(optional1)
OPTIONAL MATCH (b)-[r2:RELATIONSHIP]-(optional2)
FOREACH (o IN CASE WHEN optional1 IS NOT NULL THEN [optional1] ELSE [] END |
  CREATE (c)-[:NEW_RELATIONSHIP]->(optional1)
)
FOREACH (o IN CASE WHEN optional2 IS NOT NULL THEN [optional2] ELSE [] END |
  CREATE (c)-[:NEW_RELATIONSHIP]->(optional2)
)
DELETE r1, r2
RETURN a, b, c
```

I suspect this will be made simpler in future Cypher language updates.

PS. You probably shouldn't use `START` anymore, but I imagine you have simply for the convenience of an example.

Comment: Yep, if there were ON UPDATE/ON CREATE for relationships MERGE, I believe this would do the trick. For now, ON UPDATE/ON CREATE seems to be usable for nodes only.